# A way to track "logged in" users on Google App Engine

Tags: security, google-app-engine, session, logging, webapp2

I want to implement *logging in* for users, and regard them as "logged in" during their surfing (using *sessions*). I do it on Google App Engine with *webapp2* framework. But the platform is not important, I'm sure you will point out the general rules to do it.

I have written the class *Authorization* with *authorize* method, and every handler inherits from this class. When some handler is triggered I first run `self.authorize()` and it checks whether the user has the *session variable* holding his login. Then I check the internal datastore to find out whether the user's session is expired (so I don't depend only on the info from the client's side).

How can I improve or simplify this approach? Do I have to do the authorization routine from every handler or I can keep it in one place?

---

Also the way *webapp2* implements sessions look strange to me. I have to make a class with *dispatch* and *session* methods that do some magic. And if a handler inherits from this class I can use sessions inside it:`self.sessions['login'] = 'Joe'; self.sessions.get('login')`.

Comment: What do you store in the session variable?

Comment: @abahgat: Just the *login* of the user. The framework encodes it somehow, so I assume it is secure.